# Terminology: event raised with parameters?

Tags: .net, events, terminology

I am only not sure if one can say that event has parameters. E.g. KeyDown event. Should I say that it was raised with two parameters? What is the terminology here?

EDIT:I am trying to find out whether it is correct to say that an event is raised with parameters. Or what is the correct terminology - event with objects holding additional information?
Thanks

Comment: You need to give more context. What are you trying to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

When you send data with the raised event, its called **Arguments**.
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwa28bw2(v=vs.80).aspx